# How to structure data for accounts with multiple users in Firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm sure this has been asked somewhere, but the searches I'm doing aren't turning it up.

Here's what I would like to do in Firebase (AngularFire, to be specific):

- An account can have multiple users.
- An account has an admin.
- A user can modify any data associated with that account they are attached to, let's say
  that users create and modify Foo objects.
- If the user likes, they can designate their Foo to be visible to all 
  other users, but closed for modification.

What would the data structure in Forge be and what would the associated rules look like?

A link to an existing code sample would be a bonus.

Answer (score 4):

See [How to structure Firebase data and rules for sharing data between users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798444/how-to-structure-firebase-data-and-rules-for-sharing-data-between-users) for a comprehensive answer.

The general trick is to use the Firebase security rules to allow write access to data if the user requesting the write is present in an "authorized" list in the data itself somewhere.

Comment: There's another take on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520514/how-to-implement-collaborator-invitations-using-firebase/21539689

Comment: Thanks Anant, I appreciate it. In addition, is there a canonical example of an app with multiple users per accounts? I swear I saw one in the wild somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it again.